# Right click button on surface pen (linux mint)

Tags: linux-mint, touchscreen, microsoft-surface

I've installed linux mint 19 on my surface pro 2017. I also bought [this pen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07DFFTMS4) because it was half the price on the offical microsoft pen and it was stated that it was fully compatible. It actually works fine with a [custom kernel](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface), but there are some problem with the 2 keys (right click and eraser).

The right click is recognised by any program (like `xev`) but it is not mapped to right click in cinnamon or any application. I know that I need to use `xbindkeys` but I've never used it so I don't know what configuration to use.

I would also like to get a use for the eraser button (maybe use it for ctrl or something like that)

This is the output of `xinput`.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ipts 045E:001F UNKNOWN                    id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ipts 045E:001F Touchscreen                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ipts 045E:001F Mouse                      id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ipts 045E:001F Pen Pen (0)                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ipts 045E:001F Pen Eraser (0)             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ipts 045E:001F Pen                        id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ gpio-keys                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ gpio-keys                                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```